# Cut specific lines of a file and paste them at the end of another file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Suppose I want to cut more than one interval of lines from one file (eg., lines 1-500, 1029-1729 and 2696-3446), appending values at the end of another file (output.txt) and eliminating these values from the first file. The origin is a file with 9277 lines, I want to cut some of them, eliminating them from the original file and pasting them into another file. Is that possible via command line?

Comment: Example input and output, please.

Comment: Is my improvement in the problem description enough?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sed, you can write a set of lines to a different file while deleting it from the current file like so:

```sh
sed -i -e 'N, M { w output.txt
d }' input.txt
```

where `N` and `M` are the line numbers. The `-i` option makes `sed` save changes to the source file, and here the `d` command deletes to those lines. At the same time, `w output.txt` causes the selected lines to be written to `output.txt`. And yes, those are two separate lines: `sed` requires that the `w` command's filename be [till a newline](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Commands-Requiring-a-newline).

So you can do something like:

```sh
cmd=' { w output.txt
d }'
sed -i -e "1,500 $cmd" -e "1029,1729 $cmd" -e "2696,3446 $cmd" input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

possible !

1. copy lines to `dest.file` with redirected outout of `grep 'pattern' src.file >> dest.file`
2. delete lines from `src.file` with `sed -i '/pattern/d' src.file`